# MySQL: 10061 error but only via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm finding myself unable to connect to a MySQL server on my LAN using PHP, and only using PHP. Here's a breakdown of the situation.

- My server is at 192.168.0.999 (well, except the 999 is in the 0-255 range of course). It's an Ubuntu server, where I have MySQL 5.5 running that I installed via `apt-get`.
- I am using PHP 4 (no, unfortunately I cannot switch to 5 at this point) on Windows 7
- I am connecting using `mysql_connect()` (and again, no switching to another API is not an option at this point). `mysql_error()` says: `Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.999' (10061)`
- I can telnet to 192.168.0.999 port 3306 and although PuTTY gives me an error about packet order, there's quite clearly a MySQL server listening on that port.
- I can connect by starting `cmd` and typing `mysql -h192.168.0.999 -uusername -p`, (of course my username is not actually 'username') and after I type the password I can run queries.

I've triple-checked the credentials in my PHP script for typos, so I am now quite completely stumped. I understand that error 10061 is a network error and that either MySQL or the box it runs on, is refusing my connection, but I cannot reconcile this with the fact that I can telnet to the very same host, and can connect easily with the standard mysql client on my machine.

Before anyone brings it up, AFAICT I've followed the troubleshooting steps in the MySQL manual to a T and the PHP manual does not seem very helpful. Copying the database to my local machine is very logical, and very desirable, but also very impractical.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was connecting to the right host, but to the wrong port. For reasons that are not really relevant to the question, my MySQL instance runs on port 3307 instead of 3306, so I've set `mysql.default_port` to 3307 in my `php.ini` file.

Mystery solved: PEBKAC!

Answer (score 0):

You've stated that you are running this on windows, and that you can access MySQL through command line but not PHP.

This sounds like permissions problems - are your table InnoDB by any chance?

If so, check the permissions on the InnoDB database files.

Comment: The tables are InnoDB tables. The files themselves have rwx permissions for the owner (mysql user), and nothing for group or other. The ib* files have rw permissions for owner and group (also mysql) and no other permissions.

Comment: Just as a point of testing, change the permissions of the files to 777. I've had this issue before and I had to play around with the permissions, obviously if this fixes it then you need to correct the permissions.

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately that didn't do it.